# Найти элемент по XPath и кликнуть

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти на странице элемент по XPath и кликнуть по нему.

Нашел такую функцию:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
            return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;            
        }
```

Но результатом выполнения этой функции будет тип `Node`, у которого нет метода `click`.

Можно ли как-то привести тип `Node` к типу `HtmlElement`, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с элементом?

Comment: В смысле? Просто добавить событие клика?

Comment: @ШерзодЁров, У `HtmlElement` есть [метод `click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click). Мне нужно как-то найти элемент на странице через `XPath` и вызвать этод метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример кода, который добавляет к первому найденному элементу `onclick`:

```js
var headings = document.evaluate("/html/body//h2", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
/* Найти в документе все элементы h2
 * В качестве результата будет получен узловой итератор. */
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
thisHeading.onclick = function() {
  alert('YES');
}
var alertText = "В данном документе заголовками 2-го уровня являются:\n";
while (thisHeading) {
  alertText += thisHeading.textContent + "\n";
  thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
}
console.log(alertText);
```

```html
Hi!
<h2>Element #1</h2>
<div>Just an div element</div>
<h2>Element #2</h2>
```

Comment: Я добавил событие onclick только для первого найденного элемента

Comment: Надеюсь, я правильно  Вас понял.

Comment: Мне не нужно добавлять свои обработчики событий. Я правильно понимаю, что если у найденного элемента уже будет свой обработчик, то мне достаточно приписать `.click()`, чтобы вызывать его?

Comment: @maxwell, `.click` запустит событие. Если есть слушатели (в т. ч. и у родителей) - они сработают.